# Is $\omega_1 ^\omega$ countably compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Give $\omega_1$ the order topology, and then $\omega_1 ^\omega$ the product topology.

$\omega_1$ is countably compact, but what about this product?

I attempted to prove it in two different ways, but each time something goes wrong.  How about for arbitrary powers of $\omega_1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not hard to prove that the space $\omega_1$ is sequentially compact. The product of countably many sequentially compact spaces is sequentially compact, so $\omega_1^\omega$ is sequentially compact. Finally, in first countable spaces sequential compactness is equivalent to countable compactness, and $\omega_1$ and $\omega_1^\omega$ are first countable, so $\omega_1^\omega$ is countably compact.

**Added:** As Henno Brandsma reminds me, $X^\kappa$ is countable compact for every cardinal $\kappa$ iff there is a free ultrafilter $\mathscr{U}$ on $\omega$ such that $X$ is $\mathscr{U}$-compact; the result can be found (as part of Theorem $4.11$) in Jerry E. Vaughan, ‘Countably Compact and Sequentially Compact Spaces’, *Handbook of Set-Theoretic Topology*, K. Kunen & J.E. Vaughan, eds., North-Holland, $1984$. ($X$ is $\mathscr{U}$-compact iff each sequence in $X$ has a $\mathscr{U}$-limit, where $x$ is the $\mathscr{U}$-limit of $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ iff $\{n\in\omega:x_n\in V\}\in\mathscr{U}$ for each nbhd $V$ of $x$.) Theorem $4.9$ of the same survey says that a space is $\mathscr{U}$-compact for all free ultrafilters $\mathscr{U}$ on $\omega$ iff it is $\omega$-bounded, meaning that the range of each sequence in $X$ is contained in some compact set. The space $\omega_1$ is clearly $\omega$-bounded, so $\omega_1$ is $\mathscr{U}$-compact for all $\mathscr{U}\in\beta\omega\setminus\omega$, and therefore $\omega_1^\kappa$ is countably compact for all $\kappa$.

Comment: Ok good!  I was trying for a proof specific to this space, but that certainly works. What's your feeling on $\omega_1 ^{\omega_1} $ ?

Comment: @David: I’ll have to think a little about that one.

Comment: Using my method, we also can conclude that $\omega_1^{\omega_1}$ is countably compact.

Comment: @Brain: Could you give me some suggestions on my answer?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott all powers of $X$ are countably compact iff $X$ is $u$-compact for some ultrafilter $u \in \omega^\ast$ (I believe this is in one of the Handbook chapters). So is $\omega_1$ $u$-compact?

Comment: @Henno: Thanks: that’s the result that I was trying to remember. Yes, it is; I’ll add that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Another idea:**

It is more convient to use an equivalent definition of countable compactness. **Every hausdorff space if it is countably compact iff every countably infinite subset of $X$ has an accumulation.** Now we will use this definition to prove the question.

**Proof:** Let $A$ be a countably infinite subset of $\omega_1^\omega$. Clearly, $P_n(A)$ is countably infinite in $\omega_1^{(n)}$, where $P_n$ is the projection. Since $\omega_1^{(n)}$ is countably compact, there is an accumulation $a_n$ in $\omega_1^{(n)}$. Now let $a=\langle a_n\rangle_n \in \omega_1^\omega$. It is not difficult to see $a$ is the accumulation of $A$. This complete the proof.

Comment: If this argument worked, it would show that countable compactness is productive, but that isn’t true: see, for instance, Example $3.10.19$ in Engelking.

Comment: I do not think $P_n(A)$ will necessarily be countably infinite. Good idea though.

Comment: @Brain: Could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The points $a_n$ might be cluster points of $\pi_n[A_n]$ for subsets $A_k\subseteq A$ having disjoint closures. In that case the point $\langle a_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ wouldn’t be in the closure of $A$.

Comment: @Brian Is my comment correct?

Comment: @David: Yes, it is, but that difficulty can be overcome by assigning to each point of $\pi_n[A]$ a multiplicity equal to the cardinality of the set of points in $A$ that project to it.